# Deserialize into self in constructor

Tags: .net, vb.net, json, javascriptserializer

I would like a constructor that takes in a filename containing a JSON object

I've got files in a directory that contain JSON objects (as text)

I would like:

```
Public Sub New(filename as string)
   Dim JSONString As String = File.ReadAllText(filename)
   Dim j As New JavaScriptSerializer()
   Dim o As Object = j.DeserializeObject(JSONString)
   Me = o
End Sub
```

Obviously I can't do the line `Me = o`.

I'm wondering what tricks people can come up with.  Do I just have to replace all the calls to `New Profile(...)` to a static method?  What would you do?

I have a bunch of old calls to a constructor that took in a string, and I'd like them to use the new mechanism.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this JSON object?  Is a single variable, an array, a class, or something else?

Comment: It is a class with several properties.  The issue is that I don't want to Deserialize it to a temporary object and then set all the properties on the new object.  What happens if I add a new property?  I was curious to see if there are any tricks people use for this scenario, or if I just do something like create a static method Profile.CreateNew(filename as string) that constructs and returns the object.  (and then replace all of the calls to New(...))

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to `Me` in a constructor. "Tricks" are possible, such as reflecting over the properties of the deserialized object and assigning the same values within the constructor, but cumbersome and not sensible.

What you need is a generic helper method to deserialize an instance of any type `T` from a filename:

```
Public Shared Function DeserializeFile(Of T)(filename As String) As T
    Dim JSONString As String = File.ReadAllText(filename)
    Dim j As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Return j.Deserialize(Of T)(JSONString)
End Function
```

Usage, if the helper is in `SerializationHelper` and the class your are deserializing is, as per your question, `Profile`:

```
Dim obj As Profile = SerializationHelper.DeserializeFile(Of Profile)("filename.json")
```